# Calling JS from Applet: MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: javascript

Tags: java, javascript, url

I read that you could call JavaScript code from a Java Applet by calling

```
JApplet.getAppletContext().showDocument( "javascript:alert('Hello World');" );
```

However, when I do this i get the following error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: javascript
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same exception as you do because of that the URL class does not accept javascript: as a valid protocol.

There is a workaround though; supply an URLStreamHandler to the URL constructor.

Example:

```
final URLStreamHandler streamHandler = new URLStreamHandler() {

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u)
        throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

};

try {
    getAppletContext().showDocument(
        new URL(null, "javascript:alert('It works!');", streamHandler));
} catch (MalformedURLException me) {
    //log or whatever
}
```

Comment: This opens a new tab in Firefox, but the page and location address are both empty. Nothing happens.. :/

Comment: Nevermind, apparently my Firefox 3.0.3 on Ubuntu is bugged :) It works perfectly on other computers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    try {
        this.getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:alert('hello world');"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Works !!

Maybe the browser does not have javascript enabled.. just a guess