# liveconnect on ubuntu/firefox

Tags: java, javascript, applet, liveconnect

This works on chrome canary/firefox 4 etc on windows:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:alert('hello');"));
```

but on firefox 4 ubuntu it does nothing but throw java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: javascript

It does not throw this exception on Windows.

Any ideas on how to make this work? Even ignoring the exception using the first answer from [Calling JS from Applet: MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173617/calling-js-from-applet-malformedurlexception-unknown-protocol-javascript) the javascript does not run

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the iceatea java plug-in package, and install sun-java6-jre and sun-java6-plugin from canonical partners repository.